# why FFMPEG is not convert some audio file in 64k in android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

There are many question regarding ffmpeg and might be this should be duplicate.
I tried to convert any mp3 file in to lower bitrate 64k.
It gets successfully but some mp3 files are not converted and ffmpeg direct call to onFinish command.

Here is my command line:
according to [this](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html)

```
-i /sdcard/vk2/in.mp3 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 64k -f mp3 /sdcard/videokit/out.mp3";
```

Here is my logcate
on successfully

```
2019-12-18 04:18:26.741 7733-7733/myapp I/audioCompression: start
2019-12-18 04:18:27.104 7733-7733/myapp I/audioCompression: in_progress
2019-12-18 04:18:27.104 7733-7733/myapp I/audioCompression: in_progress
2019-12-18 04:18:42.165 7733-7733/myapp I/audioCompression: success
2019-12-18 04:18:42.165 7733-7733/myapp I/audioCompression: finish
```

otherwise

```
2019-12-18 04:18:26.741 7733-7733/myapp I/audioCompression: start
2019-12-18 04:18:27.104 7733-7733/myapp I/audioCompression: in_progress
2019-12-18 04:18:27.104 7733-7733/myapp I/audioCompression: in_progress
2019-12-18 04:18:42.165 7733-7733/myapp I/audioCompression: finish
```

report

```
       2019-12-18 05:34:45.965 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: start command : ffmpeg
2019-12-18 05:34:46.124 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
2019-12-18 05:34:46.124 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
2019-12-18 05:34:46.124 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
2019-12-18 05:34:46.124 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
2019-12-18 05:34:46.124 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
2019-12-18 05:34:46.124 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
2019-12-18 05:34:46.124 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
2019-12-18 05:34:46.124 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
2019-12-18 05:34:46.125 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
2019-12-18 05:34:46.125 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
2019-12-18 05:34:46.125 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
2019-12-18 05:34:46.125 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg [mp3 @ 0xf6519000] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 0.
2019-12-18 05:34:46.125 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg [mp3 @ 0xf6519000] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
2019-12-18 05:34:46.125 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg Input #0, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/Download/HumnavaMereSongsMp3ioRingtone.mp3':
2019-12-18 05:34:46.125 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg   Duration: 00:00:24.19, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
2019-12-18 05:34:46.125 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
2019-12-18 05:34:46.126 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg Output #0, mp3, to '/storage/emulated/0/VideoCompressor/Temp/ok.mp3':
2019-12-18 05:34:46.126 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg   Metadata:
2019-12-18 05:34:46.126 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg     TSSE            : Lavf57.25.100
2019-12-18 05:34:46.126 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 64 kb/s
2019-12-18 05:34:46.126 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg     Metadata:
2019-12-18 05:34:46.126 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libmp3lame
2019-12-18 05:34:46.126 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg Stream mapping:
2019-12-18 05:34:46.127 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
2019-12-18 05:34:46.127 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
2019-12-18 05:34:46.577 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=       6kB time=00:00:00.73 bitrate=  68.9kbits/s speed=1.46x    
2019-12-18 05:34:47.082 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=      13kB time=00:00:01.56 bitrate=  66.3kbits/s speed=1.55x    
2019-12-18 05:34:47.583 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=      19kB time=00:00:02.37 bitrate=  65.5kbits/s speed=1.57x    
2019-12-18 05:34:48.094 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=      26kB time=00:00:03.21 bitrate=  65.1kbits/s speed=1.59x    
2019-12-18 05:34:48.607 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=      32kB time=00:00:04.05 bitrate=  64.9kbits/s speed= 1.6x    
2019-12-18 05:34:49.110 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=      38kB time=00:00:04.85 bitrate=  64.7kbits/s speed= 1.6x    
2019-12-18 05:34:49.616 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=      45kB time=00:00:05.66 bitrate=  64.6kbits/s speed= 1.6x    
2019-12-18 05:34:50.117 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=      51kB time=00:00:06.47 bitrate=  64.6kbits/s speed= 1.6x    
2019-12-18 05:34:50.620 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=      57kB time=00:00:07.28 bitrate=  64.5kbits/s speed= 1.6x    
2019-12-18 05:34:51.128 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=      64kB time=00:00:08.12 bitrate=  64.4kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:34:51.635 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=      70kB time=00:00:08.93 bitrate=  64.4kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:34:52.143 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=      77kB time=00:00:09.77 bitrate=  64.4kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:34:52.651 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=      83kB time=00:00:10.60 bitrate=  64.3kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:34:53.156 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=      90kB time=00:00:11.41 bitrate=  64.3kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:34:53.659 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=      96kB time=00:00:12.22 bitrate=  64.3kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:34:54.159 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=     102kB time=00:00:13.03 bitrate=  64.3kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:34:54.676 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=     109kB time=00:00:13.87 bitrate=  64.3kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:34:55.177 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=     115kB time=00:00:14.68 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:34:55.685 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=     122kB time=00:00:15.51 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:34:56.208 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=     128kB time=00:00:16.35 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:34:56.701 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=     135kB time=00:00:17.16 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:34:57.203 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=     141kB time=00:00:17.97 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:34:57.717 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=     147kB time=00:00:18.80 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:34:58.233 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=     154kB time=00:00:19.64 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.62x    
2019-12-18 05:34:58.736 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=     160kB time=00:00:20.45 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:34:59.238 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=     167kB time=00:00:21.26 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:34:59.743 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=     173kB time=00:00:22.07 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:35:00.258 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=     179kB time=00:00:22.91 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:35:00.770 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=     186kB time=00:00:23.72 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
2019-12-18 05:35:01.017 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg size=     189kB time=00:00:24.19 bitrate=  64.1kbits/s speed=1.62x    
2019-12-18 05:35:01.017 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: in_progress command : ffmpeg video:0kB audio:189kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.130598%
2019-12-18 05:35:01.029 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: success command : ffmpeg ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
      configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
      libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
      libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
      libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
      libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
      libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
      libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
      libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
      libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
    [mp3 @ 0xf6519000] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 0.
    [mp3 @ 0xf6519000] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
    Input #0, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/Download/HumnavaMereSongsMp3ioRingtone.mp3':
      Duration: 00:00:24.19, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
        Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
    Output #0, mp3, to '/storage/emulated/0/VideoCompressor/Temp/ok.mp3':
      Metadata:
        TSSE            : Lavf57.25.100
        Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 64 kb/s
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libmp3lame
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    size=       6kB time=00:00:00.73 bitrate=  68.9kbits/s speed=1.46x    
    size=      13kB time=00:00:01.56 bitrate=  66.3kbits/s speed=1.55x    
    size=      19kB time=00:00:02.37 bitrate=  65.5kbits/s speed=1.57x    
    size=      26kB time=00:00:03.21 bitrate=  65.1kbits/s speed=1.59x    
    size=      32kB time=00:00:04.05 bitrate=  64.9kbits/s speed= 1.6x    
    size=      38kB time=00:00:04.85 bitrate=  64.7kbits/s speed= 1.6x    
    size=      45kB time=00:00:05.66 bitrate=  64.6kbits/s speed= 1.6x    
    size=      51kB time=00:00:06.47 bitrate=  64.6kbits/s speed= 1.6x    
    size=      57kB time=00:00:07.28 bitrate=  64.5kbits/s speed= 1.6x    
    size=      64kB time=00:00:08.12 bitrate=  64.4kbits/s speed=1.61x    
    size=      70kB time=00:00:08.93 bitrate=  64.4kbits/s speed=1.61x    
    size=      77kB time=00:00:09.77 bitrate=  64.4kbits/s speed=1.61x    
    size=      83kB time=00:00:10.60 bitrate=  64.3kbits/s speed=1.61x    
    size=      90kB time=00:00:11.41 bitrate=  64.3kbits/s speed=1.61x    
    size=      96kB time=00:00:12.22 bitrate=  64.3kbits/s speed=1.61x    
    size=     102kB time=00:00:13.03 bitrate=  64.3kbits/s speed=1.61x    
    size=     109kB time=00:00:13.87 bitrate=  64.3kbits/s speed=1.61x    
    size=     115kB time=00:00:14.68 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
    size=     122kB time=00:00:15.51 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
    size=     128kB time=00:00:16.35 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
    size=     135kB time=00:00:17.16 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
    size=     141kB time=00:00:17.97 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
    size=     147kB time=00:00:18.80 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
    size=     154kB time=00:00:19.64 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.62x    
    size=     160kB time=00:00:20.45 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x    
    size=     167kB time=00:00:21.26 bitrate=  64.2kbits/s speed=1.61x  
2019-12-18 05:35:01.029 10635-10635/myapp V/audioCompression: Finished command : ffmpeg
```

Comment: "but some mp3 files are not converted" Show full log from ffmpeg command.

Comment: how can i find only ffmpeg log

Comment: Capture stderr output from ffmpeg command. Or add the `-report` option and look for `.log` file in the working directory. First method is preferred as `-report` is too verbose.

Comment: here i posted my report

Comment: That's not from ffmpeg. Try using -report.

Comment: i am not understanding add the -report option and look for .log file in the working directory ?

Comment: `-report -i /sdcard/vk2/in.mp3 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 64k -f mp3 /sdcard/videokit/out.mp3";` then look for file named something like `ffmpeg-20191217-143411.log`.

Comment: report is corrected in question

Comment: `Read-only file system`. Make sure the user executing ffmpeg has write permission to the output directory. Why are you using such an old version of ffmpeg?

Comment: because i dont have more knowledge about ffmpeg

Comment: but some mp3 files are successfully converted

Comment: I have no other suggestion for you with the information given. Right now the problem seems to be related to directory permissions.

Comment: if the problem is Read-only file system than why some files are converted successfully

Comment: I realize it is probably trying to make the log in a the working directory which is read only directory, but the mp3 is in a directory that you can, I assume, write to.

Comment: please check my successfully converted log

Comment: Need a non-successful log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204455/discussion-between-tailor-and-llogan).